# Rambam's decision to merge Shofar with Succah and Lulav?

Tags: jewish-books, rambam, sukkah, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shofar

When subdividing his 14 books, Rambam decided to merge Hilchos Shofar with Succah and Lulav, allocating the first 3 chapters to the first and the last 5 to the laters (see [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah,_Shofar,_Sukkah_and_Lulav?lang=bi)) with no seeming connection between them.

Each chapter relies on its own distinctive Mitzvos and has its own Masechtos in the Talmud.

On the contrary, he made Eruvin a chapter on its own, even though it has no Mitzvos Deorayso and is all about but one detail in Shabbos Melochos.

Why?

NB: He merged some others too (Meggilah and Channuka, but those are Derabanan).

Comment: How about "Laws of Positive Commandments of Tishrei"?

Comment: @dou possible but he didn't do the same for Nisan

Comment: @msh tefillin are worn in tishrei too... don't take it too literally. these are natural group. Nisan holiday stuff. Tishrei holiday stuff. Shvitat Yom Tov. Shvitat Yom Kippur. Shabbat. Rabbinic holidays. Fast days. Seems quite natural. It'd be nice to have him say it himself of course, but this question isn't a particularly perplexing one

Comment: See Yad Peshuta intro

Comment: Shabbos vs. Eruvin: bear in mind that the laws of Shabbos are (mostly) deoraisa, while those of Eruvin are all derabanan, so it makes sense to split them up. (It's also possible that the Rambam decided that the Hilchos Shabbos unit was long enough, at 30 chapters, already.)

Answer (score 1):

There are some similarities between each of these mitzvah objects. Mitzvot of the holidays are performed with them, and they all have similar laws, and are close together on the calendar. Note that the general order for Sefer Zemanim is found in Rambam's Sefer Hamitzvot, and there, we have these three mitzvot grouped together as well (168-170), so he decided to combine them here as well.

Comment: In Sefer Hamitzvos they are not "grouped" but listed one after another. I already asked about the [lack of] order of Mitzvos in it. Rambam brings no dependency or connection between them neither he's limited in the division. Eruvin is all about Shabbos and nevertheless, it's a standalone chapter.

Comment: In addition, I was  personally heavily criticized for posting unsourced answers, I think your speculations belong in the "comments" part, not "answers".

Comment: [Maggid Mishneh, in his introduction to Sefer Zmanim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=58958#p=3), says something pretty similar to this answer: ולפי שכולם בחודש א' ואין פרטיהן מרובין והן מצוות עשה, כללן רבינו בהלכות אחדות ולא חלקן.

Comment: Theyre also the only holiday commandments women are exempt from. Shabbat Yom Kippur Pesach Shavuot TishaBav  Chanukka Purim they're fully obligated.